# Stopping my Javascript Date Countdown

Tags: javascript, date, timer, countdown

I am having issues with my timer. What I'd like it to do is when the countdown hits "0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds" I'd like it to stop right there at 0 without it displaying something goofy like "-1 days 18 hours 12 minutes 57 seconds".  Does anyone have any experience with something like this?

I guess I have had issues with my "if" statements to stop the countdown.  Here is what the code looks like:

```
<script>
    function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
        var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
        var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
        var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
        var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        return {
            'total': t,
            'days': days,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds': seconds
        };
    }

    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
        var clock = document.getElementById(id);
        var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
        var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
        var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
        var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

        function updateClock() {
            var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

            daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
            hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
            minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
            secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

            if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
            }
        }

        updateClock();
        var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }

    var deadline = 'December 16 2015 13:00:00 UTC-0800';
    initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try it like this:

```
 var timeinterval;

 function updateClock() {
        var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

        if (t.total <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timeinterval);
        }else{
            daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
            hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
            minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
            secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
        }

    }
    updateClock();  
    timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
```